# I cant scroll on my Nextjs webpage application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, scroll, navigation

I have the following issue, i have my portfolio webpage based on 3 components, Hero, About and Portfolio. The layout is the next one:

````
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Navbar />
      <main>{children}</main>
    </html>
  )
}```
````

and my page.tsx is the next one:

````
  return (
   <main>
  <HeroSection />
   <AboutMe />
   <Portfolio />
   </main>
   
  )
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `RootLayout` seems to be wrong. There should be `body` element passing the `children`.

Please refer to the [Nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required) for more information on layouts.

`RootLayout` should look something like:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Navbar />
        <main>{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Not sure what's the height of the content, but you can try  following:

```css
.content{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

In the `page.tsx` wrap your content into `div` element

```
<div className="content">
  <HeroSection />
  <AboutMe />
  <Portfolio />
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It Works! Thank you so much, the most important think was de .content styles. Again, thank you so much!